# convert GMT datetime to localtime in xslt with day light saving

Tags: xslt, dst, epoch

I am trying to convert a date in epoch using xslt in my timezone (Day light saving considered) . I am able to convert datetime to epoch but the problem is that I am getting output in epoch time in GMT but I want to convert that in my timezone ( UTC+13:00).

My input xml is something like this

```
<invoice>
<invoice_date>2016-11-19</invoice_date>
</invoice>
```

I am using below xslt

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each select="invoice">
        <EPOCH_TIME>
                        <xsl:value-of select="(xs:dateTime(concat(invoice_date,'T00:00:00')) - xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00') ) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')"/>
        </EPOCH_TIME>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output I am getting is

```
<EPOCH_TIME>1479513600</EPOCH_TIME>
```

This is all fine if time zone is GMT because 1479513600 will translate to 19-Nov-2016 00:00:00 but in my timezone this epoch time is equal to 19-Nov-2016 13:00:00.

In this xslt I am getting number of days between input date and 01/01/1970 and then converting that to number of seconds.

If there is any way I can convert the input date to my timezone and subtract  xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T12:00:00') then I would be able to sort this problem.

Can you please help me with this. Any other method for this conversion would also be perfect for me.

Comment: [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is defined as the number of seconds elapsed since midnight of 1 January 1970 **UTC** - so you should not need to consider your timezone at all. In any case, adding/subtracting a **constant** to the result is trivial. But in order to adjust the result to daylight-saving time, you will need to know the dates when DST starts and ends in your timezone.

Comment: If you just want to add 13 hours, then add 60*60*13 to the Unix time.

Comment: But, why do you want to convert the date to your timezone? You don't have an input time so it will always be the same date.

Comment: Thanks Kim and Michael for your response...Yes If I can adjust the DST then I will be able to achieve my goal...To do that I will have to know whether a date was belong to DST on to Off time.
Is there any way in xslt I can know if a Datetime belongs to DST on or off time.

Comment: @AbhayKumar No, not in XSLT. If your processor supports a call to Java, you might do it that way.

Comment: @michael.hor257k... Thanks a lot .. Yes I will have to do this in Java now. Was looking for a method to achieve this only with xslt..